# Fulpage.js only working locally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fullpage.js

I am using the fullpage.js library to make a personal website to show my portfolio using the slide page that it contains. The problem I am having is that everything works properly, but once I FTP over to my gihub.io or another public domain, I am getting GET errors to find the appropriate files out of my node modules. The path is pointing to the correct files, but when I use developer tools, I keep getting the same errors. I have copied the code below and am having the following error:

```
GET https://kghumaan.github.io/node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullPage.js 
index.html:6 
GET https://kghumaan.github.io/node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullPage.css 
index.html:1 
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://kghumaan.github.io/index.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
index.html:6 
GET https://kghumaan.github.io/node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullPage.css 
index.html:14 
GET https://kghumaan.github.io/node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullPage.js 404 (Not Found)
index.html:25 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullpage is not a function
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (index.html:25)
at i (jquery.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
at Function.ready (jquery.min.js:2)
at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.min.js:2)`
```

```html
<html>  
    <head>
    <!-- IMPORT JQUERY-->
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- FULL PAGE JS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullPage.css" />
        
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script src="node_modules/fullpage.js/vendors/jquery.easings.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/fullpage.js/vendors/scrolloverflow.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullPage.js"></script>
        <!-- FONT -->
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css">
        
      <!-- CSS -->

      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css"/>
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#fullpage').fullpage({
                navigationPosition: 'right',
            });      
        });
      </script>
    </head>    
    <body>
        <div id="fullpage">
            <div class="section" id="section1">
                <h1 id="title" class="animated fadeInUp">NAME</h1>
                    <div id="buttons">
                        <div id="button1" class="animated fadeInUp">
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="hover">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-file-o fa-stack-1x"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <br />
                            <div id="handle">
                            Resume
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="button2" class="animated fadeInUp">
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="hover">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-linkedin fa-stack-1x"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <br />
                            <div id="handle">
                            LinkedIn
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="button3" class="animated fadeInUp">
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="hover">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-github-alt fa-stack-1x"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <br />
                            <div id="handle">
                            Github
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="button4" class="animated fadeInUp">
                            <a href="#">
                                <span class="fa-stack fa-lg" id="hover">
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x icon-background"></i>
                                    <i class="fa fa-envelope-open-o fa-stack-1x"></i>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                            <br />
                            <div id="handle">
                            Email
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="section" id="section2">
                <p style="position: absolute; left: 10%; top: 3%; color: white; font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif; font-size: 120%;">Recent Work :</p>
                <div class="slide">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="..." class="animated fadeInUp" id="portfolioImage"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="..." class="animated fadeInRight" id="portfolioImage"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="..." class="animated fadeInLeft" id="portfolioImage"/>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img src="..." class="animated fadeInRight" id="portfolioImage"/> 
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is a quite clear error message: you're trying to load jQuery with HTTP but it's not allowed when the page itself is HTTPS. Fix that first and your problem might disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Your server has HTTPS and you are attempting to load jQuery from an unsecure location. This is not allowed.

To fix the issue, change this line:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The problem should go away.

Comment: That definitely fixed one of the errors but I am still getting GET errors for the rest of the files needed for fullpage.js...... I have tried everything but it will not work for some reason, thanks for your help nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullPage.css" />

    <script src="/node_modules/fullpage.js/vendors/jquery.easings.min.js"></script>
```

Use the relative path by adding a forward slash before `node_modules`.

Comment: I am still getting GET errors for the rest of the files needed for fullpage.js...... I tried adding the forward slash but am getting the same errors

Answer (score 0):

You're loading Jquery twice (and two different versions), which might cause some errors.